# Get value from curl results

Tags: php

I am using CURL to get deta from an API for cometchat and I want to retrieve the totalcount and echo it in php.

My code for the API is

```
$url = "http://api.cometondemand.net/api/v2/getUnreadMessageCounts";
$fields = array("UID"=>"$user->userID");
$fields_string = '';
foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.($value).'&'; }
$fields_string = rtrim($fields_string, '&');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('api-key:XXXXX'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (empty($result)) {
die(curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close ($ch);
$result = json_decode($result);
```

Which then Gives the response

```
{"success":{"status":"2000","totalcount":1,"usercounts":[{"UID":"279","count":"1"}]}}
```

I just want to get the "1" from either count or totalcount.

What is the best way of getting such information?

Comment: You already JSON decoded it. It should just be `$result->success->totalcount` at this point.

Comment: Actually, you also need to set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to `true` to fill that variable.